# Error al cargar una imagen de la base de datos en godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, imagen, cpanel, godaddy

tengo un problema. lo que pasa es que subi mi pagina web a godaddy, ahi contrate un dominio y un hosting para usar una base de datos. el problema es que en mis pruebas usando xampp los muestra perfectamente, pero en godaddy ya no. subo mis imagenes en base 64 y de ahi las convierto a imagen despues.
hable con godaddy pero nunca pudieron solucionar mi problema entonce sno se que hacer.
adjunto mi codigo por si algo anda mal, gracias

````
  include 'conexion.php';
  $fecha = $_GET['fecha'];
  $num = $_GET['num'];
?>
<!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Imagen sabritas">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Foto">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <body id="cuerpo">
      <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
      <div>
        <center>
          <?php
            $consu1="SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE random = '".$num."' and fecha='".$fecha."'";
            $resu1=mysqli_query($enlace,$consu1);
            while($mostrar1=mysqli_fetch_array($resu1))
            {  
                     
              ?> 
                <a id="ref" download="FotoSabritas.png" href="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($mostrar1['imagen']);?>">
                <button id="boton" style="">
                  <img id="imagen2" src="descargar.png">
                </button>
              </a>
              <a id="ref2" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode("http://www.sinsabritasnohaypartido.com/index.php?fecha=$fecha&num=$num")?>">
                <button id="boton2" style="">
                  <img id="imagen3" src="boton.png">
                </button>
              </a>
              <img id="image" src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($mostrar1['imagen']);?>"/>
              <?php
            }
          ?>
        </center>
      </div>
    </body>
  </head>
</html> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Y porque no guardas en la DB solo la url y subes a una carpeta la imagen? Es lo más conveniente.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
<?php
// Insertando imagen a un empleado
$empID = $_POST['envio_de_form']; // Este es el ID de mi registro en la DB
# definimos o creamos la carpeta destino para las Imagene por ID de empleado
$carpetaDestinoImagen = "archivos/docs/".$empID."/";
@mkdir($carpetaDestinoImagen);
# si hay algun archivo que subir en el envio del POST
if($_FILES["imagen"]["name"][0]){
    # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["imagen"]["name"]);$i++){
        # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
        if(file_exists($carpetaDestinoImagen) || @mkdir($carpetaDestinoImagen)){
            $extension = explode(".",$_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i]);
            $origenImagen= $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $nameImagen = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i];
            $urlImagen= $carpetaDestinoImagen.sha1(uniqid($nameImagen)).".".$extension[1];

            // echo 'Origen >> '.$origenImagen.'<br>';
            // echo 'URL >> '.$urlImagen.'<br>';
            // echo 'Nombre >> '.$nameImagen.'<br>';
            // echo 'Extension >> '.$extension[1].'<br>';

            # movemos el archivo
            if(@move_uploaded_file($origenImagen, $urlImagen)){
                echo 'Imagen <b>'.$nameImagen.'</b> Movida Correctamente con ruta <b>'.$urlImagen.'</b><br>';

            }
            else{ // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
                echo 'Error al Subir Imagen<br>'; // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
            } // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
        }
        else{ // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
            echo 'Error en Carpeta Imagen<br>'; // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
        } // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
    }
}
```

Partimos del hecho que tu formulario de subida usa el método POST y que el campo tipo file de la imagen tiene como id y name **imagen**.